# CsvHelper package: .netcoreapp3.0 not supported?

Tags: .net, .net-core, console, compatibility, csvhelper

I am using CsvHelper in a .Net Core console application, and getting this error when trying to build in TeamCity (it seems to build and run fine locally... is that a clue?)

```
Package CsvHelper 15.0.5 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0).
 Package CsvHelper 15.0.5 supports:
    NuGet Config files used:
          - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
        C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
          - net47 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7)
        C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config
          - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
```

Does anyone know if I just have to find another package or can I make this work somehow?

Comment: Does it compile locally?  Looks like version 15.0.5 targets Standard 2.1 https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/.  If it targets 2.1, it should be compatible with Core 3.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Answer (score 0):

You can try reinstalling the package it self. I just tried CsvHelper under .NET Core 3.0 and it is totally working fine. My CsvHelper version is also 15.0.5.

Please also verify the project version is set for .NET Core 3.0:
https://i.ibb.co/dB1nfs8/Project-Version.png

I have a public demo project on github and uploaded a working version, see line 28.
https://github.com/bricsi22/TODOApplication/blob/master/TODOApp/Controllers/UserController.cs

The example is working, but don't implement a code like this in production.